# Failed to extract_laravel8 installation problem, please give the any solution to fix it

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-8

[open image to see what code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9YTA.png)
Failed to extract symfony/http-kernel: (-1) "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.EXE" x -bb0 -y "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/tmp-2e86f4c40bb62c82b1f4351dc650c5a5" -o"C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/c609869a"

```
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with 7z command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
Install of swiftmailer/swiftmailer failed
```

57/111 [==============>-------------]  51%    Failed to extract nesbot/carbon: (-1) "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.EXE" x -bb0 -y "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/tmp-6906ac1e7f3ebeda3e29e737fe2aa95d" -o"C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/ba4590f3"

```
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with 7z command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

107/111 [==========================>-]  96%    Failed to extract fakerphp/faker: (-1) "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.EXE" x -bb0 -y "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/tmp-ff317bd9ad43cea3238c11be1b8393f7" -o"C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/e1b3f1fa"

```
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with 7z command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

108/111 [===========================>]  97%    Failed to extract guzzlehttp/guzzle: (-1) "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.EXE" x -bb0 -y "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/tmp-09908d3c783ad680df8d90a83fb405f1" -o"C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/761f6bb1"

```
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with 7z command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

109/111 [===========================>]  98%    Failed to extract guzzlehttp/psr7: (-1) "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.EXE" x -bb0 -y "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/tmp-554609d8de9b942379ef361cebae2185" -o"C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/21fb31e8"

```
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with 7z command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

110/111 [===========================>]  99%    Failed to extract nikic/php-parser: (-1) "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.EXE" x -bb0 -y "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/tmp-ac2e3f413c11488605230743d0cb8c76" -o"C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/a7c0a335"

```
The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
Unzip with 7z command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

111/111 [============================] 100%

[RuntimeException]
Could not delete C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\l1/vendor/composer/tmp-b4ecf9bc08f72c7b9e2b4b6ec2682d36:
This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [] [] []

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.